# Customize the Material 3's Switch component in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, custom-component, android-design-library, material3, switch-component

[Switch example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80MOj.png) Is there a way to customize Material 3's Switch appearance and behavior?

I have seen some examples of customized components in the Now in [Android Case Study Figma file](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1164313362327941158/Now-In-Android-Case-Study), I wonder if these components are available as a library that I can use in my app, or if there is a way to access their source code and modify them.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

I have tried to change the border thickness and the thumb size of the Switch, but I could not find a way to do that. I wonder if Google has updated the Switch component or has another new way to edit existing components.

Comment: can you please put the image of what you actually want?

Comment: I added it. This is the look I want which is similar to what Google uses in their products, not the default one in Material 3. This is from the Now in Android Figma file

Comment: Do you want to change color ??

Comment: Colors, border thickness, thumb size and adding the ability to drag the Switch

Answer (score 0):

Please check this blog. I think it will help you a little bit [link](https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-material3-switch/#:%7E:text=Anatomy%20of%20the%20Material%203,thumb%2C%20track%2C%20and%20icon.&text=For%20this%20article%2C%20create%20an,from%20the%20onCreate()%20method)

Comment: Do you mean using interactionSource?